# absolute path for file not working properly python

Tags: python, file, path, filepath

basically, I'm trying to store the full path for a file in a list but for some reason os.path.abspath() doesnt seem to work properly

```
files = os.listdir("TRACKER/")
for f in files:
    original_listpaths.append(os.path.abspath(f))

print(original_listpaths)
```

but my output seems to output this :

'C:\Users\******\Documents\folder\example'

the problem is that it should be :

'C:\Users\******\Documents\folder\TRACKER\example'

the difference is that the second one (the correct one) has the TRACKER included which is the official full path for that file but for some reason my output doesn't include the TRACKER
and eliminates it, What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
files = os.scandir("TRACKER/")
print(files)
original_listpaths = []
for f in files:
    original_listpaths.append(os.path.abspath(f))

print(original_listpaths)
files.close()
```

Comment: worked perfectly, but what's the point of file.close()?

Comment: It is used to close the  iterator object obtained by os.scandir(). For more details check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-scandir-method/#:~:text=scandir()%20method%20in%20Python,arbitrary%20order%20and%20special%20entries%20'.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your directory to "TRACKER" first. Just put `os.chdir("TRACKER")` before the loop starts after `files = os.listdir("TRACKER/")`.